# How to close a child accordion if the parent is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code for a working parent/child accordion div setup.

```
    <div class="accordion">
        <h3>Part 1</h3>
        <div class="accordion">
            <h3>Sub-Div1</h3>
            <div>
                <p>This is a sub-div</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h3>Part 2</h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is part 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the Script

```
<script>
        $(".accordion").accordion({
            header: "> h3",
            heightStyle: "content",
            active: false,
            collapsible: true
        });
    </script>
```

My question is, how to I get a child accordion to close when a parent is closed?

e.g. When the first option of the accordion is open, and its child is open, clicking the second option closes the first. But when the first is opened again, the child is still open from before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the [`activate` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate) and the [`active` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active).  Combining these with the right selectors should let you do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `activate`-function of the accordion-widget:

```
 $(".accordion").accordion({
     header: "> h3",
     heightStyle: "content",
     active: false,
     collapsible: true,
     activate: function( event, ui ) {      
         if(ui.oldPanel.hasClass('accordion')){                   
             ui.oldPanel.accordion( "option", "active", false );
         }
     }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vzgzmsvv/2/)**

**Reference:**

[active-option](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active)

[activate-function](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate)

Comment: Be wary of just using `click`.  For instance, if you tab around and use space to open/close the accordions, it won't work as expected.   This is why I suggested using the `activate` event instead

Comment: yes you're right, I found a much prettier solution.